# Angular Material 5 не работает Sidenav

Tags: angularjs, angular2, material-design

Вожусь с ангуляром в 5ой версии в связке с Asp.net Core 2. Решил добавить взамен стандартной панели навигации материаловский drawler. И... как ни странно ничего не вышло. Совсем.Как ни старался получал пустое поле. Примеры брал прямо с сайта,смотерл в stackblitz....[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ошибок не пишет,но компонент валится целиком.если применить CSS из примера получится белый прямоугольник.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не могу в упор понять почему оно не работает. Подскажите если кто сталкивался что это за чудеса?Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Самый простой вариант. Вы подключили `angular-material`?

Comment: Да, подключил. Модули импортировал.

Comment: В таком случае, посмотрите в консоли в хроме, что внутри компонента `drawer` находится.

Comment: Нвложеные элементы нет.

Comment: Ну значит не правильно подключили. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте ваш app.module